# 45 seconds latency between my Azure website and SQL database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, azure

I have a website (ASP.NET) and SQL database v12 in Azure. There is constantly a 30 ~ 45 seconds latency betweeen the two.

Symptoms:

- When I run **both** the website and the database **on my PC**, everything is instant. **This proves that
- When I run the website **on my PC** and it talks to the **database in Azure**, it is responsive enough and acceptable. **This proves that the Azure database is properly setup.**
- I tried to upgrade the pricing tier of both the database and the website to S3 standard, no effect at all.

Can someone shed some lights on this? Many thanks!

Comment: There's not enough info to go on, other than something being slow. Please edit your question with more specifics. For instance: Are your web app and your database in the same region? Is your website running in an Azure Web App (and if so, did you test multiple times, to get past the app load/warmup time)? How much data is being returned in the query? Etc.

Comment: Thank you David for your suggestion. I worked out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked out why. I was totally new to Azure so when I created the database it was created in Australia East, but when I created the app service it was created in the US.

After I recreated the app service in Australia East it is now running very fast. I started to like Azure - although their tech support was horrible - I logged a support request in Google G Suite and I got more than ten phone calls trying to help me, but there was no help from Microsoft 36 hours after I lodged the request.

Comment: Good to see you figured it out. Big performance difference when colocating services within the same region (as well as avoiding data egress charges).